# Center a Rectangle in New Window

Tags: python, computer-science, rectangles

I am trying to center a rectangle in a new created window using Python 3.2

Here is my code so far:

```
from graphics import *

def plotSquare(win, side):
    rect=Rectangle(Point(side//2,side//2), Point(side,side))

    rect.setWidth(5)
    rect.draw(win)

def main ():
    win=GraphWin("My Window", 500, 500)
    win.setCoords(0, 0, 500, 500)
    win.width=500
    win.height=500
    side=eval(input("What is the size of one side of the square (0<n<500): "))

    plotSquare(win, side)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close

main()
```

What function can I use to center the rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than positioning the rectangle at side/2, take into account the size of the window, so the left boundary of the rectangle would be 500/2 - side/2.
Same idea for the top of the rectangle.